# How can I get arrays to work with the pow() function? - C Programming

Tags: c

In the following code, I have an issue with the line:

```
watts = pow(storage[1],2)/storage[2];
```

I want to be able to have pow() use the array pointers in its calculation. However, whenever I compile the code in Pelles c, I get the following error:

> error #2140: Type error in argument 1 to 'pow'; expected 'double' but found 'double *'.

I apologize for this long block of code, but I'm a newbie to stackoverflow, and am just learning C. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

```
float watts = 0.0;
float volts = 0.0;
float amps = 0.0;
float res = 0.0;

int form_det = 0;                   //This will be the formula determiner.
int form_mod[3];                    //This will be the formula modifier.
double storage[10][10];             //This will be the storage for the numeric values.
int i = 0;                          //Declaration and initialization for 'for' loop.
int count = 0;                      //Each time the loop is executed, this is incremented.

printf("\nWhat specification of your system do you wish to calculate?");
printf("\n1.) Watts");
printf("\n2.) Volts");
printf("\n3.) Amperes");
printf("\n4.) Resistance\n");
scanf("%d",&form_det); 

if(form_det != 0);
{   
    for(i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        if(i <= 2)
        {   
            printf("\nWhat is your ");
            switch(i)
            {
                case 1:
                    printf("first");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf("second");
            }
            printf(" value to calculate? ");
            scanf("%s",storage[i][0]);

            printf("And what type of value is this? ");
            printf("\n1.) Watts");
            printf("\n2.) Volts");
            printf("\n3.) Amperes");
            printf("\n4.) Resistance\n");
            scanf("%d",&form_mod[i]);
            count++;

        }
        else
        {       
            if(form_det == 1) //Watts
            {
                if(form_mod[1] == 2 && form_mod[2] == 4)
                {
                    watts = pow(storage[1],2)/storage[2];   // (v^2)/r
                }
                else if(form_mod[1] == 4 && form_mod[2] == 2)
                {
                    // (v^2)/r
                }
                else if(form_mod[1] == 4 && form_mod[2] == 3)
                {
                    // r(i^2)
                }
                else if(form_mod[1] == 3 && form_mod[2] == 4)
                {
                    // r(i^2)
                }
                else if(form_mod[1] == 2 && form_mod[2] == 3)
                {
                    // v*i
                }
                else;
                {
                    // v*i
                }
            }   
            else if(form_det == 2) //Volts
            {
                if(form_mod[1] == 4 && form_mod[2] == 3)
                {
                    // r*i
                }
                else if(form_mod[1] == 3 && form_mod[2] == 4)
                {
                    // r*i
                }
                else if(form_mod[1] == 1 && form_mod[2] == 3)
                {
                    // p/i
                }
                else if(form_mod[1] == 3 && form_mod[2] == 1)
                {
                    // p/i
                }
                else if(form_mod[1] == 1 && form_mod[2] == 4)
                {
                    // (p*r)^.5
                }
                else;
                {
                    // (p*r)^.5
                }
            }   
            else if(form_det == 3) //Amperes
            {
                if(form_mod[1] == 1 && form_mod[2] == 4)
                {
                    // (p/r)^.5
                }
                else if(form_mod[1] == 4 && form_mod[2] == 1)
                {
                    // (p/r)^.5
                }
                else if(form_mod[1] == 1 && form_mod[2] == 2)
                {
                    // p/v
                }
                else if(form_mod[1] == 2 && form_mod[2] == 1)
                {
                    // p/v
                }
                else if(form_mod[1] == 2 && form_mod[2] == 4)
                {
                    // v/r
                }
                else;
                {
                    // v/r
                }
            }           
            else; //Resistance
            {
                if(form_mod[1] == 2 && form_mod[2] == 3)
                {
                    // v/i
                }
                else if(form_mod[1] == 3 && form_mod[2] == 2)
                {
                    // (p/r)^.5
                }
                else if(form_mod[1] == 1 && form_mod[2] == 2)
                {
                    // p/v
                }
                else if(form_mod[1] == 2 && form_mod[2] == 1)
                {
                    // p/v
                }
                else if(form_mod[1] == 2 && form_mod[2] == 4)
                {
                    // v/r
                }
                else;
                {
                    // v/r
                }
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "use the array pointers in the calculation"?  `pow` works on numbers, not pointers.  If you want to compute powers of multiple numbers, you need to call it multiple times in a loop.

Comment: What does it mean to raise an array to a power? (You also need to fix your scanf. Also, it wasn't necessary to post the whole program. Most of it is irrelevant to your problem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`storage` is a 2D array and `storage[1]` is not a `double` type. It is of type `double *` (a pointer to the row 2 of array `storage`). `pow` function expects argument of type `double`.

```
double pow(double b, double p)
```

Another big problem that invokes **undefined behavior** is

```
scanf("%s",storage[i][0]);
```

`storage` is an array of arrays of `double`s. Using wrong specifier, i.e, `%s` specifier in `scanf` for `storage` will invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you, The %s in the line was my issue. Also, gthacoder's answer helped as well. I wish I could accept both your answers.

Answer (score 0):

That error means you use the first parameter of wrong type. `storage[][]` is 2D array, so to extract any number, you need to use this notation: `storage[i][j]`. `storage[1]` is an array of double float numbers.

Apparently you should change it this way:

```
watts = pow(storage[1][0],2)/storage[2][0];
```

That will make proper calculations with the two values from the user input.

Comment: Thank you, your solution helped as well as haccks'.